# mongodump - query for one collection

Tags: mongodb, production-environment, mongodump, mongorestore

I'm trying to write a mongodump / mongorestore script that would copy our data from the production environment to staging once a week.
Problem is, I need to filter out one of the collections.
I was sure I'd find a way to apply a query only on a specific collection during the mongodump, but it seems like the query statement affects all cloned collections.
So currently I'm running one dump-restore for all the other collections, and one for this specific collection with a query on it.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to achieve this goal?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible.**

> `--excludeCollection=<string>`
>
> Excludes the specified collection from the mongodump output. To exclude multiple collections, specify the --excludeCollection multiple times.

*Example*

```
mongodump  --db=test --excludeCollection=users --excludeCollection=salaries
```

See [Details here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/index.html#cmdoption-mongodump-excludecollection)

---

**Important** `mongodump` writes to `/dump` folder. If it's already there, it will overwrite everything.

If you need that data rename the folder or give mongodump an `--out` directory. Otherwise you don't need to  worry.